# The final callback function of async.each is never called. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, async.js

This function is a part of `async.waterfall` 
The `arr` contains 2 objects with foldername, filename, width, height, etc.
I want to perform file operations on each of those files and put those 2 files in another array `photoArr`.
Then I want to pass that `photoArr` array to the next function in `async.waterfall`.
**The issue is:**
I am unable to reach the callback function, which is the 3rd argument to `async.each`. The console logs `calling next` but never logs `oops error` or `here hi`.

```
function(arr, image, callback) {
    console.log("function3");
    var photoArr = [];
    async.each(arr, function(value, next) {
        Jimp.read(`${photosDirectory}/${value["Folder"]}/${value["Photo"]}.jpg`, (err, photo) => {
            if(err) next(err);
            else {
                photo.resize(value["Size-X(cm)"] * 37.8, value["Size Y(cm)"] * 37.8).rotate(-90);
                photoArr.push(photo);
                if(photoArr.length == 2) {
                    console.log('calling next');
                    next(null);
                }
            }
        });
    }, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('oops error');
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("here hi");
            console.log(photoArr.length);
            callback(err, arr, image, photoArr);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You have `next(null)` inside the `if` condition. The whole point is it is **always** meant to call `next()` in order to "iterate". You seem have mistaken this for meaning "move to end". It does not.

Comment: You should really be using `async.map` where the iterator is then simply `(value,next) => Jimp.read(`${photosDirectory}/${value["Folder"]}/${value["Photo"]}.jpg`, next)`. Because `next` here is the callback taking `err` or the output data and "mapping" to the result array.

Comment: @Vasan It's never getting called. That's what I already told the OP. They seem to have mistaken the "iterator" callback for meaning something else.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks. That solved my issue. 